# How to determine whether the user closes browser tab or refreshes the page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, onbeforeunload

I am building a two person game app using vue.js. The app uses vuex for state management and Firestore as the backend server.

If the user leaves the app by either closing the browser tab or navigating away, the games Firestore files need to be deleted. However, if the user refreshes the page, the Firestore files need to remain so that the reload process can repopulate the game.

So I need to determine if the user has refreshed the page as opposed to closing the browser or navigating away.

As shown below, in vue's created lifecycle I setup a "beforeunload" event Listener and also start my Firestore listeners

```
created() {
    // This window event listener fires when the user
    // navigates away from or closes the browser window
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", (event) => {
        const isByRefresh = getUnloadInitiator();
        if (!isByRefresh) {
            this.stopFirestoreListeners("beforeunload");
        }
        // Cancel the event. This allows the user to cancel via popup. (for debug purposes)
        event.preventDefault();
        event.returnValue = "";

        // the absence of a returnValue property on the event
        // guarantees the browser unload happens
        // delete event["returnValue"];
    });

    this.startFirestoreListeners("created");

},
```

The getUnloadInitiator function is shown below. This is where I need help. Right now all this function does is console.log various performance values.

```
function getUnloadInitiator() {
// check for feature support before continuing
if (performance.mark === undefined) {
    console.log("performance.mark NOT supported");
    return false;
}
console.log("===============================");
// Yes I know that performance.navigation is depreciated.
const nav = performance.navigation;
console.log("nav=", nav);
console.log("===============================");

// Use getEntriesByType() to just get the "navigation" events
var perfEntries = performance.getEntriesByType("navigation");
for (var i = 0; i < perfEntries.length; i++) {
    var p = perfEntries[i];
    console.log("= Navigation entry[" + i + "]=", p);
    // other properties
    console.log("type = " + p.type);
}
console.log("===============================");

performance.mark("beginLoop");
const entries = performance.getEntries({
    name: "beginLoop",
    entryType: "mark",
});
const firstEntry = entries[0];
console.log("firstEntry.type=", firstEntry.type);

console.log("===============================");

//TODO: Determine how unload was initiated
return true;
}
```

Below is the output from my console.logs. They are the same for refreshing the page, closing the browser tab, or navigating away. All show "reload" as the navigation type.

```
===============================
nav= PerformanceNavigation {type: 1, redirectCount: 0}
===============================
= Navigation entry[0]= PerformanceNavigationTiming {unloadEventStart: 25.399999976158142, unloadEventEnd: 25.69999998807907, domInteractive: 633, domContentLoadedEventStart: 633, domContentLoadedEventEnd: 633, …}
type = reload
===============================
firstEntry.type= reload
===============================
```

Any help on how to differentiate between refreshing the page, closing the browser tab, or navigating away would be appreciated. There must be away, because the native cancel browser popup I'm using for debug purposes differentiates between fresh and browser tab close.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use a source of authority as persistence, be it firestore, local storage, or cookies. you are able to get the browser's tab ID with `tab.id` and compare it to an existing one should one exist.

```js
browser.pageAction.show(tab.id);
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Working_with_the_Tabs_API